# Partition a graph into two clusters

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, approximation-algorithms

Suppose given a complete weighted graph $G=(V,E)$, Is there an algorithm that partition $G$ into two clusters $C_1,C_2$ such that sum of heaviest edges in $C_1,C_2$ minimized?

Note that, heaviest edge in a cluster is an edge with maximum weight. Also, i rename a partition to cluster, additionally, $G$ can partitioned to two clusters $C_1,C_2$.

If there be an approximation algorithm that running time be less than $o(n^3)$ it's helpful. I find some related paper, but all paper work on metric space, but $G$ is not a metric graph.

In essence, according [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4245835/how-we-can-change-the-metric-weightetd-graph-such-that-it-remain-metric) at the first, my graph is metric, but after changing the weight of some of edges to $\infty$ then $G$ isn't remain metric.

Comment: Can you define "heaviest edges" in $C_1, C_2$ ? does this mean the sum of the one single largest edge in C1 and the one single largest edge in C2? Can you define what a 'cluster' is? Can $G$ be partitioned into any two $C_1$ and $C_2$? (So one could be a single edge and the other one be the rest of the graph?) Or do these partitions need to satisfy some other property to be considered a valid 'cluster'

Comment: @JimN I edit my post.

Comment: @NealYoung Thanks. Can you explain in more detail about your idea in answer section? Really, i can't  correctly understand your idea.

Comment: Note: OP, you have four posts, apparently about this question:
[(i)](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/50461/partition-a-graph-into-two-clusters),
[(ii)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4245835/how-we-can-change-the-metric-weighted-graph-such-that-it-remain-metric),
[(iii)](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/143766/a-question-about-euclidean-graph),
and [(iv)](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/50469/adding-a-constraint-to-input-graph).  These posts are all somewhat unclear, and cross-posting is discouraged.  I suggest you delete the other three posts.

Comment: See also OP's post [(v)](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/143630/minimize-the-sum-of-diameters-of-2-clustering-graph).

Comment: @NealYoung Yes i'm interested, thanks.

Comment: Followup post with more details about the specific problem OP is interested in: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/50494/applying-a-change-in-particular-algorithm/

Comment: @NealYoung Thanks, it's a great answer. But i think before reading your answer, i prefer to solve my problem by myself step by step, if it's possible and you are agree with me, i delete my post, because your solution is very complete and easily i can copy it that it's not good for me. If it's possible, i seek for some hint to progress my problem with myself. I forget to mentioned that in my post that i'm not agree with complete solution, because i want find solution step by step with myself. Also i have a copy of paper Monma and Suri, if you need i can scan it and send for you by email.

Comment: @NealYoung I'm not agree with complete solution delete the post, so i delete the post. If you are not agree with me, i will restore it. Thanks.

Comment: I see.  In future posts please make it clearer what you are looking for.  As it happens I spent some time thinking about how to answer your question and writing up and posting an answer for you, which from my point of view now was time wasted.  I suppose if you wanted to you could undelete the post and not look at my answer (or look at it briefly if you want to get some idea), but it's up to you. :-) As for a copy of the paper, I don't need one, thanks.

Comment: Hi Jut, I think that with the post deleted you can still see it and the answer, so deleting effectively hides the post and answer only from others.  For this reason, my vote would be to undelete it, so others can see it too.

Comment: @NealYoung Thanks for your comment. I undelete your greatful answer. Also i have a question, can i ask you?

Comment: Sure.  FYI it looks like your post https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/50494/applying-a-change-in-particular-algorithm/ is still deleted (at the moment).  A while back I made a copy with my answer here: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/50514/partitioning-points-in-the-plane-into-two-clusters-to-minimize-maximum-cluster-d

Comment: @NealYoung I undeleted the post. Can i ask my question by email? Thanks.

Comment: yes, go ahead.  Also, if you think the answer to the now-undeleted post is correct, can you go ahead and accept it?

Comment: I want be honest with you, because i find solution after reading a Thesis of a student and paper Suri, et-all, but your complete solution in the internet can be harm for my academic history. I think it's better to describe anything in Skype to you. I can't describe other things in this site.

Comment: With regard, it's very crirtical for me that describe my problem for you in a short time in Skype. Please if it's possible, accept my request. Thanks.

Comment: Jut, I'm not available to Skype, but feel free to email me.

Comment: Thank you. I send an email. With regard.

Comment: @NealYoung Yesterday, I send an email to "lastname.firstname@gmail.com". I hope you received my email. Thank you.

Comment: Jut, I did not. You'll have to substitute my actual last name and first name to get my email address.

Comment: @NealYoung Forgive me for that mistake. I sent, again an email for you. I hope you received my email.

Comment: Hi Jut, I responded to your email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Theorem 1.** *The problem admits a 2-approximation algorithm that runs in $O((m+n)\log n)$ time, given a graph $G=(V,E)$ with $m$ edges and $n$ vertices.*

[Caveat: The current post doesn't specify the objective-function value if one or both of the clusters contains no edges.  I assume that the objective-function value only sums the maximum-weight edges within clusters that do contain edges.  (If, say, the graph is bipartite then the optimal value is zero.)]

*Proof.*  Here's the algorithm:

1. let $e_1, e_2, \ldots, e_m$ denote the edges sorted by decreasing weight
2. let $G_t=(V, E_t)$ where $E_t=\{e_1,e_2,\ldots, e_t\}$
   denote the graph with only the heaviest $t$ edges
3. let $t'\in\{1,\ldots, m\}$ be maximum such that $G_{t'}$ is bipartite
   (find $t$ using binary search)
4. let $(C_1, C_2)$ be a bipartition of $G_{t'}$ (such that $E_{t'}\subseteq C_1\times C_2)$)
5. return $(C_1, C_2)$

The algorithm can be implemented to run in $O((m+n)\log n)$ time, because the binary search requires $O(\log m) = O(\log n)$ rounds, and each round requires checking whether a given $G_t$ is bipartite (and finding its bipartition, if it is), which can be done in $O(n+m)$ time using, say, depth-first search (see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph#Algorithms)).

Consider any execution of the algorithm. Let $t'$ and $(C_1, C_2)$ be as computed by the algorithm.  To finish we show that $(C_1, C_2)$ has objective-function value at most twice the optimum.

If the given graph $G$ is bipartite, then the algorithm returns a bipartition of $G$, which (by the caveat above) is an optimal solution.  So assume that $G$ is not bipartite.  So $t' < m$.

Each edge within $C_1$ or $C_2$ is not in $E_{t'}$, so has weight at most $w(e_{t'+1})$.  So the algorithm's solution achieves objective-function value at most $2 w(e_{t'+1})$.

Now consider any optimal solution $(C^*_1, C^*_2)$. Because $G$ is not bipartite, there is at least one edge within one of the clusters $C^*_1$ or $C^*_2$.  Let $e_{t^*}$ be the edge with <s>maximum</s> minimum index (and hence maximum weight) within either cluster.  The value of the optimal solution is at least $w(e_{t^*})$ (using here that the edge weights are non-negative).

Removing $e_{t^*}$ and all cheaper edges yields the graph $G_{t^*-1}=(V, E_{t^*-1})$. By the choice of $e_{t^*}$ this graph is bipartite with bipartition $(C^*_1, C^*_2)$ (as all edges within each cluster are not in $E_{t^*-1}$).  Hence $t^*-1 \le t'$, and $w(e_{t^*}) \ge w(e_{t'+1})$.  Hence the optimal solution value is at least $w(e_{t'+1})$.
$~~~~~\Box$

Comment: Excuse me, i read a paper that solve my question in with an exact algorithm in $O(n^3)$. But after reading many paper, i think, i can't do better than $o(n^3)$, so i search to find an approximation algorithm that work in $o(n^3)$ and has constant approximation factor. Are you have any comment about an exact algorithm for above problem that work in $o(n^3)$?

Comment: Specially, the first answer by @Gamow is that algorithm that unfortunately work in $O(n^3)$.

Comment: I don't have an idea for a faster exact algorithm, no.  ^^^Rather than edit your post to change your question (which would invalidate the current answers), it would be better to create a new post with the new question.  Also, please accept one of the current answers if it answers your current question, thanks.

Comment: If we want, minimize heaviest edge in $C_1,C_2$, can we reduce the running time of your algorithm to $o(n^2)$?

Comment: That's what the given algorithm does.  As described in the answer, it also runs in time $O((n+m)\log n)$, which is $o(n^2)$ unless $m=\Theta(n^2/\log n)$.  (And if $m = \Theta(n^2)$, then you're not going to get $o(n^2)$ time because any algorithm has to at least look at all the edges.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible that reference your answer to a paper? I want read the full paper of your approximation algorithm, if it's possible.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  If you're asking for a paper to cite or read, I don't know of any publication in which the algorithm appears, other than the answer here.  If you have questions, please feel free to ask them here.

Comment: excuse me, in your algorithm, if we have a constraint that say: some of pair of vertices can't belong to one cluster, how we can handle this in your algorithm? suppose we can't add weight +$\infty$ to handle that.

Comment: Yes, easily: just modify the algorithm above to define each $G_t$ to also include all the edges that you don't want included in any cluster.  This is exactly the effect you would also get by giving them weight $\infty$ (which also works), so I'm a bit perplexed by your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i can't undersant why $t^*-1\leq t'$. Can you explain more about it?

Comment: Good question.  I should have defined $t^*$ as the edge with *minimum* index within either cluster (I've fixed the post so that it says that).  So each edge $e_i$ that is within either cluster (that is, that doesn't cross between the two clusters) has $i \ge t^*$.  So, removing all such edges ($e_{t^*}, \ldots, e_{m}$) yields a bipartite graph, specifically the graph $G_{t^*-1}$ (as defined in the algorithm.  But $t'$ is the maximum index such that $G_{t'}$ is bipartite.  So $t' \ge t^* - 1$.

Comment: Hello, Suppose $G$ is metric and contains exactly $n$ vertices, also we say two a bi-partition of $G$ is a good, if and only if, sum of diameters of $C_1+C_2$ be less than diameter of $G$.

Comment: (i) The lemma fails (consider vertices (a, c, b) with c in between a and b and forbidden pairs (a, c) (c, b).  (ii) Given that there is an O(m log n)-time algorithm (above), depending on what you mean by "black box", the answer to your question is technically yes.  Just don't use the black box -- solve the problem in O(m log n) time directly.  Jut, you may have more luck if you make your questions more precise.  You keep asking many related but (in my opinion) somewhat imprecise questions, which makes it hard to give definitive answers.  Perhaps you could give a statement of your precise goal?

Comment: Thank you so I read again and I will ask you in precise manner about the problem, if get stuck. for (i) if we each point appear exactly in one pair, are there any counter example?

Comment: Yes, there is a counter-example.

Answer (score 2):

The problem even seems to be solvable in polynomial time.
Let us call $C_1$ the **black** cluster and $C_1$ the **white** cluster.
We test for every two edges $e_1,e_2\in E$ whether there exists a bipartition so that $e_1$ is the heaviest edge in $C_1$ and $e_2$ is the heaviest edge in $C_2$. In the end, we ouput the bipartition that minimizes the sum of the two heaviest edges.

Now the test for two edges $e_1,e_2\in E$ proceeds as follows.
We use a 2-SAT formulation.
There is a variable $x(v)$ for every vertex; the value TRUE corresponds to $v$ being black and the value FALSE corresponds to $v$ being white.

- For any edge $e=\{u,v\}$ with $w(e)>w(e_1)$, we require that $u$ and $v$ are in different clusters. Hence we create the clauses $(u\lor v)(\lnot u\lor\lnot v)$.
- For any edge $e=\{u,v\}$ with $w(e_1)\ge w(e)>w(e_2)$, the two endpoints must either both be in $C_1$, or one is in $C_1$ and the other one in $C_2$.
  This corresponds to the clause $(u\lor v)$.
- Edges $e=\{u,v\}$ with $w(e_2)\ge w(e)$ are ignored for this particular test.

Comment: Thanks, what is running time of your algorithm?

Comment: There is a paper that solution is identical with your solution but the running time is $O(n^3)$, so it's not good for my question, because i trying to find a solution that work in $o(n^3)$.

Comment: So, why didn't you provide us with full information on the known results around your problem (in the statement of your question)??? And PLEASE provide a link to that other paper with the $O(n^3)$ algorithm.

Comment: FWIW I think this algorithm can be implemented (by enumerating all first edges and using binary search over the second) to run in time $O(m(m+n)\log n)$, which is $o(n^3)$ for sufficiently sparse graphs (as long as $m$ is $o(n^{3/2} /\sqrt{\log n})$).